# print record from Mulitple tables for a specfic record in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a database of coke studio.In this data base a seasons has multiple programs recorded and multiple songs are performed/recorded in the program, also a song has multiple
musical keys below are the normalized tables of my Database

```
seasons -> season_id(pk), name
programs -> program_id(pk), name
programs_recorded -> p_id(pk), season_id(fk), program_id(fk)
songs -> song_id(pk), title
songs_performed -> s_id, song_id(fk), program_id(fk)
musical_keys -> song_id(fk), music_keys
artist -> artist_id(pk), song_id(fk), name 
musician -> musician_id(pk), name, song_id
band -> band_id(pk), song_id(fk), band_name
band_member -> member_id(pk), band_id(fk), member_name
instrument -> instrument_id, instrument_name 
musician_plays -> m_id(pk), musician_id(fk), instrument_id(fk)
member_plays -> mem_id(pk), instrument_id(fk), member_id(fk)
```

Note: A song is performed in program by artist, Musician, Band so songs primary key is in artist, musician and band as foreign keys.Also  Musician and Band uses Instruments to record songs.Band has band members.

My Query is:
For a specific record, list all the instruments and the key notes(musical keys) that have been used to produce the record?

Note: My record is my Program_id.

My solution is :

```
SELECT title, instrument_name, music_keys FROM seasons, programs_recorded, programs, songs_performed, songs, musical_keys, artist, musician, musician_plays, band, band_member, member_plays, instrument WHERE `seasons`.`season_id`=`programs_recorded`.`season_id`
AND `programs_recorded`.`program_ID`=`programs`.`program_ID` AND `programs`.`program_ID`=`songs_performed`.`program_ID` AND 
`songs_performed`.`song_id`=`songs`.`song_id` AND `songs`.`song_id`=`musical_keys`.`song_id` AND musician.song_id=songs.song_id
AND musician_plays.musician_id=musician.musician_id AND musician_plays.instrument_id=instrument.instrument_id AND artist.song_id=songs.song_id
 AND band.song_id=songs.song_id AND band_member.band_id=band.band_id AND member_plays.member_id=member_plays.member_id
 AND member_plays.instrument_id=instrument.instrument_id   
GROUP BY songs_performed.song_id AND songs_performed.program_id=12000 ;
```

This query doesn't show anything. What I am trying to do is connecting all the table so that I can print all the instrument and key notes(musical_keys) for a specific record. In my case 12000 program id has 3 songs. One performed by artist( artist don't use any instrument) one by musician( musician uses instruments) and last one by band(band has band members and they use instruments)

Kindly tell me if my Database design is correct or not I mean can I run this query on my database or not. If Yes then kindly give me the code. 
Thanks in advance :)

Note: 
tools used Wamp server,Sql yog.

Comment: Do not use comma-join syntax. Also, in the absence of any aggregating functions, do not use GROUP BY. Under certain circumstances it's liable to return unexpected or erroneous results. See the DISTINCT operator

Comment: I suspect your design is flawed. But that's OK - this kind of thing is notoriously complicated.

Comment: OK then now I will use Inner joins instead of comma-join syntax. but still I am confused about the design . I know that I need all the tables for this query to run properly but I don't know this whether I can join a single table with 3 other tables ?

Comment: I tried USing Inner join and also removed the Group by syntax but still output is blank. I think there is some special syntax for join a table with 3 tables.

Comment: can Anyone help me with the correct syntax ? I need it urgently

Comment: It's not simply a question of syntax. It's a problem of database design. An urgent fix requires professional help. That's not what we're about. For a start, a program can belong to only one season, so why have a separate table for program_season? It's a normalization step too far.

Comment: yeah.. Program is only in One season but There can be 2 or may be 3 programs in a season. Programs_recorded is a Table where both season and program ID are connected.

Comment: Yes. So you store the season that the program belongs to within the `program` table. Simples. You're not doing anything wrong (there). You're just adding uneccessary complexity.

Comment: I know its complicated. Can you do me a favor ?
please make a query for me because if I change me design now I will have to change all my other queries as well and that's not possible for me now  ? Any confusion you have ? I can explain.

Comment: I can't - but someone else might!